# How to set up office webcam with no computer?

Tags: webcam, video-streaming

I'd like to set up an office webcam so people in remote offices can see what's going on in our main office. Ideally we'd just get some webcam that works without needing to plug into another computer, i.e. the webcam would just stream directly and/or be controllable over the network. I'm not sure how this would work ... e.g. can it join skype or google hangouts ... and perhaps it's just easier to join to an old PC. Any ideas? How is this sort of thing usually done?

So far I've bought a Logitech c920, but that was before I thought about doing it without a PC. If there's a type of webcam I can buy that doesn't need a PC then I'm up for getting that instead.

Comment: You could use a wireless webcam, no need for it to be connected to a computer, most have an interface that you can browse too over the network and internet to view the video feed.

Comment: Yes; There are stand-alone web cameras both wire and wireless that allow you to do this.  The `Logitech c920` does not.

Comment: what's the terminology I'd use to search for such webcams?